# Exact meaning of "natural de" in a curriculum vitae?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, definiciones

In a Spanish-language curriculum vitae, I came across the item *Natural de:*, which I don't understand.  It is in the "Personal Data" section (*Datos personales*).

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE.  Please be aware we are not a translation service.  That doesn't mean your question can't be asked here, but it is a bit border-line. We also like to stick to a single question per question. I have edited your question to be a single question--you may wish to ask a second question about the second phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Natural de... -Country-" - Means he is native from such country/city/whatever

Btw, it's not "Dator" but "Datos" - meaining Data or Information

And yes, "Formación" is related to the education or training he's had.

You're welcome

Answer (score 3):

Por favor, consulta como mínimo el diccionario de la RAE (http://dle.rae.es/Natural) antes de preguntar aqui.

La segunda acepción es:

> .2. adj. Nativo de un pueblo o nación. U. t. c. s.